# Make QLabel text selectable?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QLabel` in my application that displays error messages to the user. I would like to make the text of the label selectable so users can copy and paste the error message if needed.

However, when I use the mouse to click and drag over the text, nothing happens - the text is not selected.

How can I make the text within a `QLabel` selectable by the mouse?

Comment: Downvoter - care to explain why this is a bad question? How can I improve it?

Comment: I have not downvoted, but the question can be answered with a minimum of research (for example reading the documentation). This is the prefered way instead of asking questions prematurely. You have even answered the question yourself after a few minutes.

Comment: @Skalli - You must not be familiar with the SO article [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). I actually answered the question immediately using the built-in "Answer your own question feature". I was showing the research that I did in my answer because reading the documentation and a quick Google search actually did *not* help me, and I wanted to save others the time in the future.

Comment: That makes sense and I take back my previous statement. I didn't know about the article and I guess this question qualifies in that matter. :)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

**Code**

The text of a `QLabel` can be made selectable by mouse like so:

```
label->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextSelectableByMouse);
```

This is found in the [QLabel documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qlabel.html#textInteractionFlags-prop).

You can use that same function to make links selectable by keyboard, highlight URL links, and make the text editable. See [Qt::TextInteractionFlag](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qt.html#TextInteractionFlag-enum).

**Designer**

Search for `textInteractionFlags` under the `QLabel` menu and set the flag `TextSelectableByMouse`.

Comment: In case you want the mouse cursor to change on hover, you can add :
`label->setCursor(QCursor(Qt::IBeamCursor));`

Comment: In case you came from Google looking for how to do this in PyQT 6:
`QLabel(text).setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextInteractionFlag.TextSelectableByMouse)`

Answer (score 6):

Here is another method, for reference...
You could create a QLineEdit subclass instead, tweaked to look and act like a QLabel,
in the constructor:

```
 setReadOnly(true);
 setFrame(false);
 QPalette palette = this->palette();
 palette.setColor(QPalette::Base, palette.color(QPalette::Background));
 setPalette(palette);
```

I think the accepted answer is simpler and preferable to this though.