# Select tab text in QTabBar

Tags: c++, qt

How can the text of a tab in a `QTabBar` be selected using the mouse?

The text within a `QLabel` can be selected as described here: [Make QLabel text selectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957749/make-qlabel-text-selectable), but I haven't found a similar with to do this for `QTabBar` tab text.

The documentation for `QTabBar` can be found here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabbar.html. It mentions "select" several times, but none of those instances have to do with selecting text. Rather, they all have to do with selecting the tabs themselves.

Comment: Could be [this thread](https://forum.qt.io/topic/10141/solved-changing-qtabwidget-s-tab-name-at-runtime/2) of any help?..

Comment: Looking through the source code of QTabBar and QTabWidget, tabs don't seem to be displaying their text via a QLabel, and definitely don't expose interaction flags like QLabel does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt does not natively propose to make `QTabBar` text selectable.

However, they let you add your own widgets to the tab itself using [QTabBar::setTabButton](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabbar.html#setTabButton). Then, you can create the tab with no title (`""`), and then add a `QLabel` with your title and make it be selectable.

Note that clicking the `QLabel` itself does not change current tab, you'll need to handle that manually (done in the sample code below).

Here is a sample code that works (text of both active and inactive tabs can be selected):

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTabWidget>
#include <QTabBar>
#include <QLabel>

#include <map>

class MainFrame : public QMainWindow
{
public:
    MainFrame()
    {
        tabWidget = new QTabWidget( this );
        setCentralWidget( tabWidget );

        addSelectableTab( new QLabel( "Hello World", tabWidget ), "foo" );
        addSelectableTab( new QLabel( "Hello World", tabWidget ), "bar" );
    }

    void addSelectableTab( QWidget* widget, const QString& title )
    {
        int index = tabWidget->addTab( widget, "" );

        QLabel* titleLabel = new QLabel( title );
        titleLabel->setTextInteractionFlags( Qt::TextSelectableByMouse );
        tabWidget->tabBar()->setTabButton( index, QTabBar::RightSide, titleLabel );

        tabLabels[titleLabel] = index;
        titleLabel->installEventFilter( this );
    }

    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) override
    {
        /** When using QLabel as tab title, current tab can only be changed by clicking outside
         *  the label...so let's detect when user clicked inside the label and then change current tab!
         */
        if ( event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease )
        {
            auto found = tabLabels.find( dynamic_cast<QLabel*>( obj ) );
            if ( found != tabLabels.end() )
            {
                if ( !found->first->hasSelectedText() )
                {
                    // suppose user clicked the label
                    tabWidget->setCurrentIndex( found->second );
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return QMainWindow::eventFilter( obj, event );
    }

private:
    QTabWidget* tabWidget;

    // this is to know what tab should be activated when a label is clicked
    // you may get rid of that by using QTabBar::tabButton to identify what
    // tab a QLabel is related to
    std::map<QLabel*,int> tabLabels;
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);

    MainFrame wnd;
    wnd.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

And now tab titles are selectable:

[image]